# Do better Pokemon spawn when you're without Pokeballs?

Tags: pokemon-go

Yesterday I ran out of Pokéballs at the beach and then I saw some better Pokémon spawns nearby (Pinsir and Nidoking or Nidoqueen).

I wondered if it was just that I was lucky or it was some kind of trick made by Niantic to make us spend Pokécoins.

Comment: just lucky/unlucky

Comment: Don't give Niantic ideas!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since spawns are the same for everyone, one person having no pokeballs would have no influence on the spawnrate of rarer pokemon.